# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'bar'

Tags: python

I am using python 3.6 and am a learner. Below is a simple code of a sin wave.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import seaborn as sb

smartphone = pd.read_csv("C://Users/Admin/smartphones.csv")

count = smartphone.Ram.value_counts()
category = count.index
plt.bar(category,count)
plt.xlable('Ram')
plt.ylable('Count')
plt.xticks([1,2,3,4])
plt.yticks([1,2,3])
plt.show()`
```

I am receiving the error "AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'bar'" Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are importing the wrong thing. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` instead of `import matplotlib as plt`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you see other people's code and they have `plt.bar(x,y)` or `plt.show()` the `plt` they are referring to is a sub-module of the `matplotlib` package called `pyplot`.

So this is really what's going on:

```py
import matplotlib

matplotlib.pyplot.bar(count, category)
...
...
...
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

So if you are mainly using `pyplot` what you want to do at the top of your script is,

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then you can just:

```py
plt.bar(count,category)
...
...
...
plt.show()
```

***edit:*** Also just wanted to add, that I think you have a typo and have `xlable` and `ylable`, but it should be `xlabel` and `ylabel`. Your code will throw errors if you don't fix that.